# Hooking -> changing Data forever

Tags: python, c++, windows, hook

Well I'm working now on a project that took me more time than I thought.
I stuck at hooking; I want to change a program ( it's a simple qvm file that is provided by a freeware game that's based on the quake 3 engine) using C++... with HOOKS!

So there's where I stuck. I don't know how to do this or if there is any way that makes it even possible (I'm using C++ and Python on Windows ). I simply don't know what to do, no idea :(.

I hope you know how to make it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!
Can you please explain more about your particular problems with concrete examples of what you have tried and what exactly caused compiler or runtime errors? Usually you will implement hooking (or callback) methods as static functions in C++.

Comment: Well, I want to modify a qvm file that's included in the game Urban Terror 4.1, I tried it with a Hex Editor but too complicated

Comment: So please elaborate what exactly do you mean with `HOOK`. I thought you want to write some C++ code that should be called back by a library.

Comment: So I guess you want to change some .qvm binary data using a C++ program, am I on the right track?? If so, why not using one of these [QVM editors](http://file.downloadatoz.com/qvm-editor.html)?

Comment: Did you download this yet? there's nothing such like a download link. Or am I blind? :D

Comment: I've just googled this list, you might do a better research since you know what you really need ...

Comment: OK, sorry! The result list doesn't really mention s.th. really QVM related.

Comment: I know :) have been googeling for ages. There's nothing. I've been also looking at gamedeception, and I got only the tipp to hook them .

Comment: Sorry again! But then it's all about you want to change .QVM files using C++, right? Is there a reasonable format description of .QVM files available? It's mentioned that these are 'compiled' formats somehow. What does this mean exactly, referring to plugin symbols or functions from the engine? I really don't get the context, it seems to be something very specific of the game engine environment. May be you should add an appropriate tag.

Comment: Well .qvm s, you can compare them to .dll, they telling the game engine how to work :)
Give a look to this -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quake_III_Arena#Engine

Comment: Then it's all about knowing the required virtual engines instruction format to change these kind of files. If you have access to the appropriate interpreter documentation or sources you might learn from these what exactly to do.

Comment: Yeah, well same answer I exactly found on another site 5 min ago, but well thank you :) for your help on this topic :)